# Program fails when called from python subprocess but works from console with same arguments

Tags: python, subprocess

Been tearing my hair out for a couple of days, hoping someone can save me and see something obvious!

I am trying to run a command from python on Windows using Spyder IDE (as part of anaconda). The specific command is this in case it matters (changes the size of an svg image)

```
rsvg-convert -a "OriginalFile.svg" -w "300" -f svg -o "NewFile.svg"
```

From the command prompt all kinds of variations work successfully e.g.

```
rsvg-convert -a OriginalFile.svg -w 300 -f svg -o NewFile.svg
rsvg-convert -a C:\OriginalFile.svg -w "300" -f svg -o C:\NewFile.svg
```

so it seems like rsvg is not super fussy
I have also copied the command into a Test.bat and run the bat file which also works.

From python nothing works! I have added the rsvg-convert executable directory to my PATH for now It is able to find the rsvg-convert.exe (I believe this to be the case since it complains if Shell=True is not used) but nevertheless it fails with the same arguments

```
origin_path = 'C:/OriginalFile.svg'
target_path = 'C:/NewFile.svg'
subprocess.run(['rsvg-convert',
                   '-a',
                   origin_path,
                   '-w', str(300),
                   '-f', 'svg',
                   '-o', target_path], Shell=True)
```

I have also tried several variations e.g. subprocess.call, hardcoding 300 as '300' etc. If I catch the error result I get return with ***error (code 1): None***. This also indicates that rsvg has been found but doesn't give much clues to why it is failing with identical arguments. I have built the string manually to double check that this really is the case

```
command = 'rsvg-convert -a' + origin_path + ' -w ' + str(300) + ' -f svg -o' + target_path
print(command)
subprocess.run(command, Shell=True)
```

I have also tried to go via the bat file also with no luck, variations like

```
subprocess.run('C:/Test.bat', Shell=True)
subprocess.Popen('C:/Test.bat', Shell=True)
```

I am not familiar with python (obviously) so just trying to get what I thought would be a simple script but it has well and truly beaten me! Can anyone save the day for me?

Comment: The arguments aren't identical. In your console example, you used backslashes, while in Python, you used forward slashes.

Comment: My recommendation is: Look at the two process creations (working and failing) and see what's different in the command line (and perhaps current path, environment, etc.). You can do that with [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) - set a filter as `Operation` `begins with` `Process`.

Comment: @CherryDT Oh my goodness, from my first test, it seems like you are right about the backslashes! Can't believe that I didn't spot that after all those hours. Thank you so much for taking the time to read and comment, you can't understand how much fixing this issue has helped me :D